# Preserving non-numerical columns when using combn in R

Tags: r

I have a data frame similar to the following format:

```
Doc Category val
A   aa        1
B   ab        6
C   ab        3
D   cc        6.....
```

I am using the following code to identify all combinations of sums of val and then extracting the rows that add up to a target sum I have already identified.

```
#all combinations
res <- Map(combn, list(val), seq_along(val), simplify = FALSE)
x=unlist(res, recursive = FALSE)
z=lapply(x, function(x) sum(x))
```

My issue is determining the best way to preserve the character columns in the data frame as the code above only gives numerical values. The way I am doing it now is a mapping based on val, which normally works fine, however, I can run into issues when there are duplicated values.

For example, if my target sum is 7, I eventually want output that looks like this (there are other ways to get to this value, but for now just returning the first instance works):

```
Doc Category val
A   aa        1
B   ab        6
```

Is there a better way to map to the non-numerical columns to achieve this output ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would this solution work for you:

```
df <- data.frame(Doc = LETTERS[1:7],
                 Category = c("aa","ab","ab","cc","ca","cb","bb"),
                 val = c(1,6,3, 6, 4, 5, 2), 
                 stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
df
#   Doc Category val
# 1   A       aa   1
# 2   B       ab   6
# 3   C       ab   3
# 4   D       cc   6
# 5   E       ca   4
# 6   F       cb   5
# 7   G       bb   2


target.sum=7

# create an "id" variable that is equal to the index of all rows
df$id <- seq_along(df$val)
id.res <- Map(combn, list(df$id), seq_along(df$id), simplify = FALSE)
x=unlist(id.res, recursive = FALSE)

#remove all elements in the list where the sum of 
# values in column val is not equal to target value
x.list <- lapply(x,FUN=function(x){ if(sum(df$val[x]) == target.sum ) df[x,] else NA})

#remove missing values
x.list <-x.list[!is.na(x.list)]

x.list
# [[1]]
#   Doc Category val id
# 1   A       aa   1  1
# 2   B       ab   6  2
# 
# [[2]]
#   Doc Category val id
# 1   A       aa   1  1
# 4   D       cc   6  4
# 
# [[3]]
#   Doc Category val id
# 3   C       ab   3  3
# 5   E       ca   4  5
# 
# [[4]]
#   Doc Category val id
# 6   F       cb   5  6
# 7   G       bb   2  7
# 
# [[5]]
#   Doc Category val id
# 1   A       aa   1  1
# 5   E       ca   4  5
# 7   G       bb   2  7
```

Comment: This appears to be exactly what I needed. I figured I needed some sort of id, but I was struggling on how to incorporate it into my existing code. Thank you so much !